# how to encrypt api access credentials in xamarin forms

Tags: api, security, xamarin.forms

I have a simple Xamarin Forms application that retrieves data from a web service using basic authentication. The user does not need to authenticate, so the credentials for accessing the api are written in the rest service class. The issue is that if someone later decompiles the code, they will be able to see the credentials. Is there a way to make these more secure?